# Дан файл целых чисел. Выбрать наименьшее из чисел, принадлежащее интервалу [a,b]. С#

Tags: c#

Помогите пожалуйста.
Дан файл целых чисел. Выбрать наименьшее из чисел, принадлежащее интервалу [a,b]. Концы интервала a и b вводятся с клавиатуры.

```
    string filePath = @"C:\Users\Rande\Desktop\Учеба\ekzamen\diapazon\NewFolder1\numbers.txt";
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(filePath))
        {               
            string[] array = line.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (string s in array)
            {
                int n;
                if (int.TryParse(s, out n)) numbers.Add(n);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Прямо код Вам дать?

Comment: У меня есть код, как достать из файла данные. Я только не знаю как в интервале найти наименьшее

Comment: Как бы Вы это делали на листке бумаги?

Comment: А если таких нет, какой должен быть результат?

Comment: Таких это каких?

Comment: лежащих в интервале

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто сделать это так же как и поиск минимума с одним условием.

```
int min = Int32.MaxValue; // Или b + 1 
foreach(int x in numbers) {
    if(a <= x && x <= b) {
        min = Math.Min(x, min);   
    }
}
if(min > b) //такого числа нет
```

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо